# javafx FXML Canvas empty after drawing

Tags: canvas, javafx

I'm using Intellij IDEA for javafx FXML development. I used the following code to simply draw an rectangle. However, it never showed up.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
public Mat image;
@FXML public Canvas img = new Canvas(300,300);
public GraphicsContext gc = img.getGraphicsContext2D();
@FXML private void drawCanvas(ActionEvent event) {
    gc.setFill(Color.AQUA);
    gc.fillRect(10,10,100,100);
}
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        System.out.println("color set to black");
        gc.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
        System.out.println("draw rectangle");
    }
}
```

I used setFill() and fillRect() both in Button OnAction and initialize methods. But it still doesn't draw the rectangles.

**sample.fxml**

```html
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <top>
      <ToolBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <items>
          <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#drawCanvas" text="draw" />
        </items>
      </ToolBar>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="co" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="9.0" text="co" />
            <Label fx:id="rgb" layoutX="144.0" layoutY="13.0" text="RGB" />
            <Label fx:id="zoom" layoutX="245.0" layoutY="9.0" text="zoom" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </bottom>
   <center>
      <ScrollPane fx:id="img_pane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <content>
            <Canvas fx:id="img" height="286.0" width="355.0" />
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several questions like this on this forum, but I cannot find them with a quick search.

You should ***never*** initialize a field that is annotated `@FXML`. The whole point of `@FXML` is that the field is initialized during the process of loading the FXML file.

So in your class initializer, you create a `Canvas` and then assign `gc` to its graphics context:

```
@FXML public Canvas img = new Canvas(300,300);
public GraphicsContext gc = img.getGraphicsContext2D();
```

Then, when you load the FXML file, the `FXMLLoader` creates a new `Canvas` as described by the FXML, assigns that new canvas to the field `img`, and places the new canvas in the scene graph (which you then display in the stage). However, `gc` is still the graphics context of the original `Canvas`, which you never display. So any graphics operations on `gc` will never be realized.

You need

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Canvas img ;

    private GraphicsContext gc ;

    @FXML private void drawCanvas(ActionEvent event) {
        gc.setFill(Color.AQUA);
        gc.fillRect(10,10,100,100);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        gc = img.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        System.out.println("color set to black");
        gc.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
        System.out.println("draw rectangle");
    }

}
```

Comment: wow! thanks for the detailed lesson. I learned javafx fxml by myself, however there really aren't so many tutorials out there. So everything that is marked with `@FXML` shouldn't be initialized rather than giving the value in the initialize method, correct?

Comment: If a field has an `@FXML` annotation, don't initialize it. The `FXMLLoader` will initialize it for you, assuming everything is set up correctly. The initialization of `@FXML`-annotated fields is guaranteed to happen before the `initialize()` method is called. The documentation for `FXMLLoader` is woefully inadequate...