# JavaFX Canvas in Spring

Tags: spring, canvas, javafx

how to integrate small canvas in an Spring Application?

something like fxml-pane with
canvas
button
label
input

and draw cicle on press button, or an string, 
but all still in the Spring contex

I can't find good examples with spring+fx

I have

```
public abstract class FXMLController
    implements InitializingBean, Initializable {
...

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    loadFXML();
}

protected final void loadFXML() throws IOException {
    try (InputStream fxmlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fxmlFilePath)) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setController(this);

        this.view = (loader.load(fxmlStream));

    }
}

public Node getView() {
    return view;
}
```

and

```
public class DemoController
    extends FXMLController {
 ...
@FXML
public void drawCanvas() throws Exception{

        //Group root = new Group();
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(25,25,25,25);
        r.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        root.getChildren().add(r);
        calcCanvas.getScene().setRoot(root);
}
```

but the whole pane is overwriten,
I would like to add just my rectangle to the small canvas and keep the buttons from fxml

something like 
scene.getRoot().getChildren().add(r);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with this
[javafx FXML Canvas empty after drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310900/javafx-fxml-canvas-empty-after-drawing)

and this
https://codelife.de/2015/02/27/javafx-8-with-spring-integration/

editing root was the wrong way
you need gc = calcCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D(); in initialize() method